# Emulator for Android Studio doesn’t launch

Tags: software-rec, android-studio

Emulator for Android Studio 3.6 Canary 9 not launch when run app. Before that it worked well, but suddenly I got this:

```
7:15 PM Emulator: WARNING: unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
7:15 PM Emulator: Unexpected feature list: DynamicPartition MultiDisplay VirtioInput VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUV420888toNV21 YUVCache
7:15 PM Emulator: WARNING: load_config.cpp:123: Verified boot config  version is too large to be  supported. major_version = 2, supported = 1.
```

My laptop:

- core i7
- 12G ram
- 64-bit
- Windows 10

Comment: thanks you for answer my question, but how updating the emulator, I tried this way (SDK Tools updating remove and installing) But it didn't work.

Comment: Try using another version of Android system image. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by reinstall Android Emulator in Android Studio, like **moumouh206** notice:
*Algrorithm A:* File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK
switch to SDK Tools *uncheck* **Android Emulator** (my version here was 31.2.10) to uninstall, then close Android Studio. Open again and repeat *Algorithm A* but in the end Check **Android Emulator** to install again, then again close Android Studio and restart your mashine. Should work now.

Comment: Didn't work for us.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, you have to update your emulator in sdk manager:

1.launch sdk manager

2.settings->appearance and behavior->system settings->android sdk

3.SDK Tools

```
Update Android Emulator
```

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X73lF.png)